# flutter macos desktop -- Push Notifications -- FBLPromises not loading

Tags: flutter, macos, push-notification, dyld, flutter-macos

I have a big Flutter macOS desktop project that uses many plugins.
Everything works perfectly until I add the "Push Notifications" capability.
As soon as this entitlement is added, I cannot launch the application anymore (in debug mode).
I systematically get the following error:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/Versions/A/FBLPromises
```

I spent a lot of hours, looking for a solution on the Internet but none have worked so far (including the use_frameworks! or use_modular_headers!, ...)

I am running XCode 15.0.1, Flutter 3.16 on Mac mini (Ventura 13.6.1).

I am targeting macOS 10.15

Here is the list of Pods

```
app_links
App.framework
connectivity_plus
desktop_drop
device_info_plus
file_selector_macos
Firebase
firebase_analytics
firebase_core
firebase_messaging
FirebaseAnalytics
FirebaseCore
FirebaseCoreInternal
FirebaseInstallations
flutter_app_badger
flutter_local_notifications
flutter_native_timezone
FlutterMacOS
FlutterMacOS.framework
FMDB
fvp
GoogleAppMeasurement
GoogleDataTransport
GoogleUtilities
mdk
nanopb
open_document
package_info_plus
path_provider_foundation
photo_manager
Pods_Runner.framework
PromisesObjC
ReachabilitySwift
share_plus
shared_preferences_foundation
sign_in_with_apple
sqflite
sqlite3
sqlite3_flutter_libs
thumblr_macos
url_launcher_macos
video_player_avfoundation
wakelock_plus
webview_universal
window_size
XCFrameworkIntermediates
```

The entitlements are in DebugProfile.entitlements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And I repeat... as soon as I remove the "Push Notifications" capability, it is working...

Any help will be more than welcome.

Thanks in advance,